# Looking for Visual Studio utility to manage 'license block' in all source files of a project

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I've been asked to add a block of text to each source file of an existing project which will contain a short copyright notice and a reference to the main license file.

Do you know of any VS utilities or separate apps which can do this?

Ideally I'd like to be able to run this multiple times such that it would update any existing license block.

I'm using VS2008 and most of the source is C#

Thanks,
Canice.

Answer (score 1):

Does the copyright notice need to be checked into source control, or just be available when the code is zipped up?  If you only need it when the code is being packaged, you could use a placeholder at the top of your files, something like

```
// -- LICENSE INFO HERE --
```

Later, you can use a batch file, msbuild, or powershell to replace all instances with your specific license text just prior to zipping up the code.

Comment: The copyright doesn't have to be checked into source control.

I'm using a Setup Project in the solution to build a Source Code Installer, so I'm not copying or zip'ing the files beforehand. I could use a post-build command to do as you suggested but I was hoping that there is a utility already out there for this.

I can't spent a lot of time on it as its a once off project (not a product) for our customer.